# Functions With Memory

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to come up with a self-contained pseudo-random number generator function which will not repeat the previous output.

The obvious not self contained solution would be:

```js
let lastX = -1;

function uniqueNumber(range) {
    let x = Math.round(Math.random() * range - 0.5);
    if (lastX == x) return uniqueNumber(range);
    else {
        lastX = x;
        return x;
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(uniqueNumber(5))
}
```

However I'd like the function to be self contained and having the variable outside of the function seems rough. We could encapsulate the variable and function into a object but I'm trying to come up with a self contained function.

I've came up with a solution using the browser storage as a pseudo memory, but it feels a bit overkill using long term storage as temporary memory:

```js
function uniqueNumber(range) {
    let lastX

    if(localStorage.getItem('numberwang') === null) lastX = -1;
    else lastX = localStorage.getItem('numberwang')

    let x = Math.round(Math.random() * range - 0.5);

    if (lastX == x) return uniqueNumber(range);
    else {
        localStorage.setItem('numberwang', x)
        lastX = x;
        return x;
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(uniqueNumber(5))
}
```

Is there a more subtle way to achieve the same outcome, like possibly saving the last result to a RAM address?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use `localStorage` or some other complicated procedure. You can just encapsulate `lastX` in a closure to avoid exposing it as a global variable:

```js
const uniqueNumber = (() => {
  let lastX = -1;

  return range => {
    let x;
    
    do {
      x = Math.round(Math.random() * range - 0.5);
    } while (lastX === x);

    lastX = x;
    return x;
  };
})();

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(uniqueNumber(5))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems a lot more sensible. I've got a few questions regarding the answer if you don't mind sparing a moment.  Apologies if it's dumb but I've only been doing JS for a few weeks, and those nested arrow functions have went a little over my head.  What's happening on lines 1 - 4 to allow the lastX constant to stay instantiated after the function has been completed?  Also why are we placing brackets round the entire function? Thanks again :)

Comment: The `(...)` are just a good style to make clear that this is the expression that then gets called by the following `()`. Functions can access the variables of the function they're inside of. If you do so after the parent finished executing this still applies, and that's what you call a closure.

Comment: @JonasWilms the `(...)` are _required_ for immediately invoked arrow functions or it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your question (about keeping things "self-contained" is to ALWAYS **pass external entities as parameters**. This is essentially the same thing as closing over them, but passing things as parameters can be beneficial for testing purposes.

```
const createUniqueNumberGenerator = lastX => uniqueNumber = range => {
 // your existing code
}

const myGenerator = createUniqueNumberGenerator();
const rand = myGenerator(10);
```

Comment: Thanks! I've had a play around with that code and got it working! :)